# Get the seconds number from timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, modulo

I can get the seconds from a time stamp with this command :

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
```

From this time stamp 146573139**8**013 I will get this result 146573139**8**, 
What I need is only the last number, 8 in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged your question [modulo](/questions/tagged/modulo), which is actually the answer: You use the [`% operator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3):

```
long x = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 10;
// modulus/remainder operator ---------------^
```

That will give you only the values 0-9, the last "digit" in the decimal number.

---

("modulus" and "remainder" aren't really synonymous although they're frequently used that way in programming. There are various types of "modulo" operations which vary based on their handling of the two operands' sign; [more on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).)